# Wubi Error Executing command

Tags: 13.04, wubi

**Wubi** gives me error executing command:

[image]

```
command=C:\Windows\System32\bcdedit.exe /set {79d57369-10fa-11e2-a539-af7634f5111e} device partition=F:
retval=1
stderr=An error has occurred setting the element data.
```

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 and Higher, Use Wubi by Hakuna Matata To Install Wubi on Windows Laptop/Computers without using a USB Stick.

**Wubi Hakuna Matata download from the wiki: [https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki]**

If you want to do other Linux OS, you can use Unetbootin or Rufus

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this is the wrong answer, but it sounds like you're trying to install Ubuntu to a Windows Dynamic Disk:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363785%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737048.aspx

Neither Wubi nor the GRUB bootloader support this, you'll need to install to a Basic Disk.